# How to write fluent methods for a type in C#

Tags: c#, android, methods

I understand extension methods are a style of programming that let us invoke different methods of the same type without having to create a new instance of that type.

I have used this method several times in Android Java. I do [Xamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin) Android applications development and most of the times when I want to create an AlertDialog, I would need a builder class which is encapsulated in the same like below:

```
// Import the dependency
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;

// Create an instance of an alert dialog
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).SetTitle("Mytitle").SetMessage("This is my message!").Show();
```

Now suppose I have a similar class like that in my own custom code. How do I define methods that behave  the same way? I also noticed that after you call the method  `new ...Builder.Show()`, you are not allowed by the compiler to add more extension methods. How do I achieve that?

Here is my code:

```
class Builder{

    // Defining the class variables
    Context ctx;
    string title, message;

    public Builder(Context context){
         this.ctx = context;
    }

    // How do I write extension methods such as setMessage and setTitle?
    void SetTitle(string title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    void SetMessage(string message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    // Define a method for showing the builder, which when after invoked, the
    // other two methods cannot be allowed to be invoked
    void show(){
        // Display the builder
    }

}
```

Comment: These are not extention methods.  What you're talking about is fluent methods.  To achieve this you just need to make each method return the object it's called on like `public Builder SetTitle(string title) { this.title = title; return this; }` so that you can then chain other fluent methods after that one.

Comment: @juharr, but they are invoked like extension methods where you do not need to create a new instacne of the type to invoke the method, Now that they are fluent methods, How do I achieve that?

Comment: Extension methods are static methods that you can call as if they are instance methods on an object.  The idea is they allow you to extend a type without changing it like `public static string FirstHalf(this string x) => x.Substring(0, x.Length/2);` can be called like `var x ="Hello".FirstHalf();`  and you could chain any method that is defined on `string` or is an extension method of `string` after that but it has nothing to do with it being an extension method, just the fact that you can chain methods.

Comment: Also _extension methods are a style of programming that lets us invoke different methods of the same type without having to create a new instance of that type_ is not correct.  You have to have an instance of the type the extension method is defined on.  Extension methods mean you don't have to include the name of the static class they are defined in, which is maybe what you meant.  And your example definitely is using an instance of a class.  Chaining means you don't have to assign it to a variable and then call the methods on separate lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not extension methods. What you're talking about is fluent methods. To achieve this you just need to make each method return the object it's called on so that you can then chain other fluent methods after that one.

```
class Builder
{
    //defining the class variables
    Context ctx;
    string title, message;

    public Builder(Context context)
    {
        this.ctx=context;
    }

    public Builder SetTitle(string title)
    {
        this.title=title;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder SetMessage(string message)
    {
        this.message=message;
        return this;
    }
    
    public void Show()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the compiler check to make sure .`Show()` is the last in the chain of the methods?

Comment: There's no way to ensure `Show` is definitely called at all, but you would not be allowed to chain after `Show` because it's a `void`.  So `builder.SetTitel("Title").SetMessage("Message");` will compile and not complain about a missing `Show()`, but `builder.Show().SetMessage("Message");` would complain because you cannot call `SetMessage` on a `void` return type.

Comment: You actually _can_ somewhat force an order if you return interfaces, which allow only a certain course of action. The "last" one (commonly the one with the 'build' method) then returns you the usable final type you wanted the builder to build.